# How to identify the network performance issue?

Tags: server, google-cloud-platform, network-programming

I am a little confuse about my message server's network bottleneck issue. I can obviously found the problem caused by the a lot of network operation, but I am not sure why and how to identify it.

Currently we are using GCP as our VM and 4 core/8G RAM for our message server. Redis & Cassandra is in other server at the same place. The problem happened at the network operation to the redis server and cassandra server.

I need to handle 3000+ requests at once to save data to redis and 12000+ requests to cassandra server.

My task consuming all my CPU power and the CPU usage down right after I merge the redis request and cassandra request to kind of batch request. The penalty is I have to delay my data saving.

What I want to know is how can I know the network's capability of my system. How many requests within 1 second is a reasonable task?. As my testing, this is obviously true that the bottleneck is the network operation, but I can't prove it. I can't even know how to estimate a reasonable network usage of my system? Are there some tools or other thing that can help to my make sure my network's problem? Or this is just a error config of my GCP system?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: Network performance goes up with the size of the instance. You will need to perform benchmarks to determine your configuration's maximum performance. Your question is not one that can be answered on SO. You will need to do the testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "monitoring" label in each instance where you can check through graphs values like instance CPU, Network and RAM usage.
But to further check the performance of your instance you should use StackDriver Logging[1](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/) and Monitoring[2](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp). It stores a lot of information from the internal servers and the system performance. for that you will need to install the agent in the instance. It also stores information about your Load Balancer[3](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/choosing-load-balancer), in case you are using one with your web application, which is very advisable since it scale your resources up or down with intelligent Autoscaling.
But in order to test out your network you will need to use some third party tool to overload the network. There are multiple tools to achieve this, like JMeter.

---